# distributing $n$ identical objects to $r$ groups with each group receiving a different number of objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have $20$ identical objects to distribute to $6$ different groups, but each group has to receive a different number of objects. How many ways to do it?

I know the way to distribute $n$ identical object to $r$ different groups is the same method as stars and bars formula $n+r−1 \choose n$.

But I don't know how to do with restriction "each group has to receive a different number of objects". (A group can receive no objects.)

Comment: Can some group have no objects? Because $\sum_{i=1}^6i=21>20$

Comment: Yes, group can have no object, but not more than 1 group, since they have to recieve different number of object.

Answer (score 3):

Start off with $0+1+2+3+4+5=15$. The ways to add the remaining $5$ objects to this while retaining order and distinctness correspond to the partitions of $5$ (e.g. $5=2+3$ corresponds to $0+1+2+3+(4+2)+(5+3)$), [of which there are $7$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Examples). You can assign each of the resulting partitions to the $6$ groups in $6!=720$ different ways, so the total count is $7!=5040$.